# If $\sin^{-1} x > \cos^{-1}x$, then $x$ should lie in the interval

Tags: trigonometry

[image: My solution]

But the answer is $$\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right).$$
Can anyone tell what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: You are correct and they are incorrect.

Comment: Ok maybe they did it was mcq and it was the only Near option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}2$; $\cos^{-1}1=0$

$\because\frac{\pi}2>0\Rightarrow\sin^{-1}1>\cos^{-1}1$

Therefore, $1$ satisfy the inequality. So, you are correct.

See the graph,

[image]